# C# Regular expression for combination of space, alphanumeric and special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am using asp.net 3.5 with C# 2008.

I have a textbox and to validate it I have a regular expression validator. For allowing Alpha-numerics, space and certain special character I am using following regular expression `ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9_. ,'#&$~@!-]*"`

Now I want to allow `double quotes (")` as a special character. For this I have tried `ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9_. ,'#&$~@!\"-]*"` and `ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9_. ,'#&$~@!"-]*"` etc. but gives Parser Error.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `"` using `""` or `&quot;`

Your regex should be

```
^[\w. ,'#&$~@!&quot;-]*$
```

`\w` is similar to `[a-zA-Z\d_]`

Comment: @Dev what kind of error is it showing..check out the edit..try removing \ before ""

Comment: I used follwing : ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9_. ,'#&$~@!""-]*$" and the error is "Parser Error : The server tag is not well formed." However if I removed the double quotes from the regular expression then it doesn't gives error.

Comment: @Dev you should have `runat="server"` attribute..is it there

Comment: <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revMname" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMname" ErrorMessage="Enter letters only" 
                                            ValidationGroup="a" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9_. ,'#&$~@!\"-]*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Comment: Means? In regular expression?

Comment: ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9_. ,'#&$~@!;quot;-]*" don't gives parse error but gives validation message on insertion of " in textbox.

Comment: Worked !! :) Your new edit has worked.. Thank you so much.. :)